# Where pseudo version with non-existent tag

Tags: git, go, go-modules

When importing a `GOPATH` style dependency from in a go.mod enabled module, I get a mysterious pseudo-version.

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
$ go mod init github.com/foo/test
go: creating new go.mod: module github.com/foo/test
$ go get github.com/bar/api@master
$ cat go.mod 
module github.com/foo/test

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/bar/api v3.9.1-0.20190923092516-169848dd8137+incompatible // indirect
)
$
```

The `github.com/bar/api` repo has only a `v3.9.0` tag defined. The `master` branch is a few commits ahead of that.

Does anyone know where the `v3.9.1` tag is being picked up from? That tag does not exist. The commit id, `169848dd8137`, does point to the `HEAD` of `master`, but it is not tagged. Is it just `go mod` just being clever and saying hey, commits after the `v3.9.0` tag imply some version of `v3.9.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a 'pseudo-version', explained here:

https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Pseudo_versions

In short, since you picked @master, it creates this version with the timestamp and hash of the latest commit on the master branch. The version number is generated from the latest tag +1 revision.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. Here's the info from the link mentioned above -

> vX.Y.(Z+1)-0.yyyymmddhhmmss-abcdefabcdef is used when the most recent
>   versioned commit before the target commit is vX.Y.Z.